# How to embed fonts to fast report in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fonts, report, fastreport

I'm using Fast Report in my Asp.net MVC Project.

I used some fonts in my report designer that end user may doesn't have these font in his system. so I have to embed these fonts to report. But I don't know how can I do this.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything to do it.

**Edit**
At local all of  things is OK but when I upload my project on server and open in my browser, fonts isn't shown.

Comment: As far as I know, this cannot be done for the report files (FR3) themselves. The FR3 is a document that describes the report's component structure to the Fast Report engine. Embedding a font at this stage would require that the Fast Report previewer and report designer act as if the font were really available on the system. You might want to contact the vendor about this.

Comment: @Majid Basirati How do you ended up with this?

Comment: did u find a solution?